# Triggering click from Electron main script

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

How can I trigger a button click from Electron main script?

In my project, I have the HTML file with a button that I'd like to simulate a click, a javascript file where I define some behaviors with JQuery and the main javascript file which is the main Electron process.
The Electron's main process should send a command to the rendering process to trigger a button click, but I can't access the rendering from the main.js. What options do I have to do this?

Comment: Post your code to provide more explaining...

Answer (score 0):

Main process and renders are communicate with **ipc**